# Connecting to Azure App Insights from powerBI

Tags: azure, powerbi-desktop, appinsights

I would like to connect to my azure app insights instance from powerBI desktop to prepare dashboards based on the log data. However, I don't see any adapter for app insights from get data option. How do I go about doing this? What I need really is the last step in this document. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/export-power-bi Looks it's completely removed now.

Answer (score 1):

> What I need really is the last step in this document. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/export-power-bi Looks it's completely removed now.

No you don't. You need to use the other steps as outlined in the section [Export Analytics queries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/export-power-bi#export-analytics-queries).

Basically this means you can write any kusto query to get data from App Insights (see the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/log-query/get-started-portal)) and use (the resulf of) that query in your Power Bi report. When the report is activated the query will be send to App Insights and return the results.

It is less easy than having some kind of "Get Data" method but it is way more powerful because the Power BI Adapter, which is now deprecated, only created static uneditable queries.